# How do I correct c++ memory leaks with my binary search tree pointers?

Tags: c++, data-structures, memory-management, binary-search-tree

I'm applying some operations to some data structures on C++. I read the operations from a CSV file, calculate CPU time, and write it to another CSV file.

I'm doing this for hundreds of sets of operations, however, after several applications of make_experiment(), I get the following error:

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'St9bad_alloc' what(): std::bad_alloc

Apparently it may be because for some reason I ran out of memory. What could be going wrong? ABB is a BST.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
typedef unsigned int uint;

string PATH_IN = "ops/";

struct node{
    uint data;
    node* left;
    node* right;
};

class ABB{
    private:
        node* root;
        node* insert(uint x, node* t);
        int find(node* t, uint x);

    public:
        ABB();
        void insert(uint x);
        int search(uint x);
};

node* ABB::insert(uint x, node* t){
    if (t == NULL){
        t = new node;
        t->data = x;
        t->left = t->right = NULL;
    }
    else if(x < t->data)
        t->left = insert(x, t->left);
    else if(x > t->data)
        t->right = insert(x, t->right);
    return t;
}

int ABB::find(node* t, uint x){
    if(t == NULL)
        return 0;
    else if(x < t->data)
        return find(t->left, x);
    else if(x > t->data)
        return find(t->right, x);
    else
        return 1;
}

ABB::ABB() {
    root = NULL;
}

void ABB::insert(uint x) {
    root = insert(x, root);
}

int ABB::search(uint x) {
    return find(root, x);
}

void make_experiment(string tree_type, string exp_type, int n){

    // Declaration of variables
    ABB abb;
    ifstream file_in;
    ofstream file_out;
    string line;
    string op;
    string sval;
    uint val;
    int found;

    // Opening input and output files
    if(exp_type == "r"){
        file_in.open(PATH_IN + "random/random_" + to_string(n+1) +  ".csv");
    }
    file_out.open(tree_type + "_" + exp_type + "_" + to_string(n+1) + ".csv");

    // Dealing with headers
    getline(file_in, line);
    file_out << "op,time_ms" << endl;

    // Applying operations and writing elapsed time to output CSV
    while(getline(file_in, op, ',')) {
        file_out << op << ","; 
        getline(file_in, sval);
        val = (uint)stoul(sval);
        if(op == "i"){
            if(tree_type == "abb"){
                abb.insert(val);
            }
        }
        else if(op == "be"){
            if(tree_type == "abb"){
                found = abb.search(val);
            }    
        }
        else{
            if(tree_type == "abb"){
                found = abb.search(val);
            }
        }
        file_out << "time_elapsed" << endl; 
    }
    file_in.close();
    file_out.close();
}

int main(){
    for(int i=0; i<1000; i++){
        make_experiment("abb", "r", i);
        cout << "ww" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input CSV files look like this, with a million rows:

```
operation,value
i,771383893
be,4071986422
i,2493790208
bi,297183474
```

Usually it works until i≈250, correctly creating the corresponding output files, and then the error comes.

Comment: I see one `new` and zero `delete`. Did you try debugging the code? Truly running out of memory is quite rare nowadays, how much memory does the process use?

Comment: I also see an acyclic data structure where nodes clearly belong to the structure. Consider using `unique_ptr`?

Comment: You definitely have a large memory leak. You leak every node you create. `ABB` has no destructor, never frees anything and it should handle the rule of 3 / 5 /0.

Comment: Assuming 64-bit architecture, `sizeof(node)` would be probably 24 bytes. Assuming 1/3 of tour file calls insert, that's 333 thousand nodes, or 7.6 MiB data. You then repeat that 1000 times without ever freeing the memory. 7 gigabytes of data is quite a bit. Now, assuming 32-bit architecture, `sizeof(node)` could be 12 bytes, which lands at 3.5GB, which is more than maximum allowed for that architecture in C++ (max heap for 32-bit C++ is 2GiB).

Comment: how should ~ABB() be? I don't get how to delete instances of a struct, or nodes linked to several other nodes.

Comment: Just like you insert nodes, but in reverse order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most probable cause is that fact that you create and allocate a raw pointer in your private `insert` function:

```
node* ABB::insert(uint x, node* t){
    if (t == NULL){
        t = new node; //< new pointer created
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

then pass it to your root data member in your public version of `insert`:

```
void ABB::insert(uint x) {
    root = insert(x, root);
}
```

but then don't ever destroy/deallocate the `root` member pointer when you're done (i.e. when an `ABB` object is destroyed).

The easiest way to correct this is to delete the root pointer in `ABB`'s destructor (which you would explicitly declare and define):

```
ABB::~ABB(){
   delete root;
}
```

Similarly, you need a destructor for `node`, so that every node's left and right pointer gets recursively freed, otherwise all the BST leaves will still have memory leaks (note that there's multiple ways to implement this, mine is a *very basic* example implementation; you should look into an implementation that suits your needs the best):

```
node::~node() {
    delete left;
    delete right;
}
```

You can use `std::cout`s or your debugger to visually see how these destructors work

I would also look into completely reworking the design (specifically the private `insert` function and maybe even the private `find` function) to not have to allocate and pass raw pointers in a separate function, because, though *unlikely*, memory can leak if something like an exception occurs while `root` is still being assigned:

```
node* ABB::insert(uint x, node* t){
    if (t == NULL){
        t = new node;
        t->data = x;
        t->left = t->right = NULL;
    }
    else if(x < t->data)
        t->left = insert(x, t->left);
    else if(x > t->data)
        t->right = insert(x, t->right);
    return t; //< exception occurs somewhere in the function before this line
}
void ABB::insert(uint x) {
    root = insert(x, root); //< root is never assigned; t is still allocated but not freed
}
```

More importantly, if you somehow end up using the private `insert` function somewhere else in your program, **you may forget to delete that specific pointer** and have the same problem all over again. This won't be a problem if your `insert` doesn't return a raw pointer.

An even better solution **(if you have C++11 or newer)** is to rework the design to use smart pointers such as [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) instead of raw pointers, since smart pointers have built in [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) and will manage the pointer de-allocation for you:

```
struct node{
    uint data;
    std::unqiue_ptr<node> left;
    std::unqiue_ptr<node> right;
    //Destructor no longer needed in this minimal example
};

class ABB{
    private:
        std::unqiue_ptr<node> root;
        std::unqiue_ptr<node> insert(uint x, node& t);
        int find(node& t, uint x);
    public:
        //No destructor or contructor needed in the minimal example
        void insert(uint x);
        int search(uint x);
};
```